# Chrome Extension Development open extension window from background service

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, metamask

Using: **Manifest V3**

**How do I open my extension** same way Metamask does it?

Currently what I have tried is that from my background service I am using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to send message to my content.html and .js of my extension where I have `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` and listen for the open window message then I tried with `chrome.extension.getViews({ type: 'popup' }).forEach(v => v.open());` to display my extension window, but instead it sometimes opens a new empty tab or sometimes I get error `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

What I want to accomplish is that the service worker which is constantly running in background, can open my extension window **same way like when I click on extension icon**.

Metamask case example: https://youtu.be/vhUjCLYlnMM?t=633

**This:**

> From [ **(Service worker)** `background.js` ] **open extension window** programmatically, same way
> as when clicked in the Chrome taskbar on the icon of extension.

Comment: See `chrome.action.openPopup`

Comment: @wOxxOm I see in documentation but dont seem to have that option when I try the openPopup does not exist. I have tried with await chrome.action.getPopup({tabId: undefined}) and I get the alhlkhdlkashdkalhdkalhd.html which is exactly the html of popup

Comment: It's currently in development, so it's [restricted to dev channel](https://crbug.com/1245093). In stable channel, you'll have to open a new window using chrome.windows.create.

Comment: @wOxxOm how Metamask does it?

Comment: It doesn't open the popup. It simply adds a DOM element to the web page, which you can inspect in devtools.

Comment: User clicks on a link on the website, website requests to show extension window, and extension window shows up. Take a look at example: https://youtu.be/vhUjCLYlnMM?t=633

Comment: The video is inconclusive, but it's definitely not an extension popup. It's either a DOM element in the page that imitates the window, which you can inspect in devtools like I said, or it shows a standard popup window using chrome.windows.create({type: 'popup', url: 'popup.html'}).

Answer (score 0):

You can open it with a new tab on the url in the css and js parts.
`<a target="_blank" href="file.url"></a>`

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is not what I am trying to accomplish, please read my question and please note that I am working on extension of Chrome not a regular html page.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? I'd like to help :)

Comment: What I exactly need is to keep extension working at all times not only when clicked on it. However the content.js seems to dispose once you click elsewhere in chrome and reload from start each time extension icon is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation but used a different tactic. Rather then relying on the content script, I am using the options page as the dispatcher.

I am not sure whether this helps in your situation, as I am not sure whether you want to open a new tab or a popup. This works for a new tab, but not for a popup.

Looking at [chrome.runtime API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-openOptionsPage), I found only one method that opens a new tab directly: chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage(). For this to work, you need to define an option page in your manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  ...
  "options_ui": {
      "open_in_tab": true,
      "page": "options.html"
  },
}
```

Note that the options page must be bundled with your extension. But if you open it in a tab, you can perform a redirect to wherever you want to be, for instance:

```
window.open("https://www.whereever.com","_self")
```

If you need to configure the destination, chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage() can take a callback function as an argument, which you can use on the options page to figure out the final destination page(s).